# Do we need a DNS server when we use OpenDNS?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns, opendns

I am in the process of splitting roles up from one server to 5.

The current server is running as a DNS server, among other things. The DNS server just has a forwarder to the OpenDNS IP addresses and the workstations have the IP address of the local server as their DNS.

I understand the benefit of having one role per server, but when I am dedicating an entire server to forward all requests to an external service - I wonder if it's required. Would I be better making the router go through OpenDNS and then setting each of the workstations DNS to the router IP?

I would be interested to know the 'norm' for DNS servers and if you think it's necessary for my situation. Maybe you would suggest software to run on the DNS server to mimic what OpenDNS is doing but gives me greater control? (i.e. no limitations to the number of exclusions or white list addresses.)

**My Situation**

~40 Workstations running Windows XP Professional SP3
4 Servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
1 Server running Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)

1 PoE Managed Switch
1 Managed Switch

All workstations can access the internet but are restricted by the OpenDNS service.

---

**Current Server Setup**
(HP ProLiant ML110 G6 Intel Xeon 2.40GHz - 1GB of RAM being upgraded to 5GB)

1 Server is running the following roles:

1. Active Directory Domain Services
2. DNS Server
3. File Services
4. Windows Deployment Services (not being used)

**Planned Server Setup**

HP ProLiant DL360 G4 Intel Xeon 3.0GHz - 4GB of RAM
Active Directory Domain Services

HP ProLiant DL360 G4 Intel Xeon 3.0GHz - 4GB of RAM
Active Directory Domain Services (Additional Domain Controller)

HP ProLiant DL360 G4 Intel Xeon 3.0GHz - 4GB of RAM
DNS Server?

HP ProLiant ML110 G6 Intel Xeon 2.40GHz - 1GB of RAM being upgraded to 5GB
File Server (because it's a tower and hopefully cheaper to add multiple hard drives.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Active Directory ? If so you can't really use an external DNS server for internal users. 
Also it would be more beneficial for us if you update the question with specifics where each roles go and how you want to split it.

Basically if your environment works with AD you **can't** point your workstations to external dns servers as the workstations need to know how to find your AD controller, how to find each other, how to find other servers. Considering that you do have 40 workstations I presume you must be using Active Directory (otherwise it would be waste of resources not to).

Actually if you do have Active Directory on your server you can't set it up without DNS so if you're splitting roles up it should be something like (bare in mind I don't have knowledge what you have in your network):

1. Server 1 - AD/DNS
2. Server 2 - SharePoint
3. Server 3 - SQL
4. Server 4 - Exchange
5. Server 5 - 2nd AD/DNS -> if it's different physical machine, otherwise it won't matter as much as when the physical machine is down whole AD/DNS is down.

EDIT: considering your update

1. Server 1 - AD/DNS (primary)
2. Server 2 - FileServer
3. Server 3 - AD/DNS (secondary) - different physical server

Also since you seem to have some free space you could put `SharePoint Foundation 2010` in your network and have nice little place for your users to share their work. It's really useful even in such small places. I do have similar setup and having Sharepoint as a central store for files is far better then simple FileServer (of course Fileserver has it's goodies - but SharePoint is good for working on documents - history of changes etc)

Comment: Yep, we're using AD. I'll update my question with the current/planned server setup.

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly recommend keeping DNS on an internal server; though with it's a lightweight and very stable role and with a network of your size, It's certainly not necessary to reserve an entire server for it.

The main issue here, is that you'll also need a DNS server that supports Dyanmic Updates for your internal network, since a lot of Active Directory requires it. (If you want to do this with a DNS that isn't Windows' own, then be prepared for a lot of pain.)

I suggest turning off the router DNS, enabling the AD-integrated DNS role on *two* of your servers (This will be full master/master, so you won't need to worry about replication) and ensuring both servers are passed to the clients by your DHCP server. You can still forward referrals to OpenDNS for the rest of the world.

This is probably the easiest configuration route and also gives your network an extra bit of resilience.

Comment: So have a master DC and a slave DC but configure the DNS on both to OpenDNS. If/When the master fails the slave will take over and use the pre-configured DNS settings?

Comment: First thing to note is that the concept of a Primary and Backup domain controller died with Server 2003. In your setup, all domain controllers are authoritative. The same goes for AD-integrated DNS, changes can be made on any member and they will be fully propagated to the others.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I only have master DC's, no slaves? That would explain quite a lot!

Comment: You still have 1 or the other being the 2ndary DNS server. Those dns server should have forwarders set to OpenDNS or GoogleDNS to resolve external queries but your DHCP should be assinging both of your internal servers to your internal clients for AD to function properly.

Comment: @SmallClanger There's always master and slave server in AD. Second server can be GC but there are far more roles that are located on the Master server... It's granted that you can use both of the servers with same results and it will be invisible for users but still there's quite a difference between Master and Slave AD server, you can't demote the Master without some complications and you can demote Slave if it's only role is GC without any problems.

Comment: True. The server IPs still need to be configured via DHCP and you do need to specify the *order* in which they're checked, so one of them will be a primary in that sense. However, to be clear to the OP, that's the only place where any precedence exists. Changes made to any AD-Integrated DNS server on the same domain will propagate to the others, the same way changes to AD will.

Comment: @MadBoy - Ah, we're getting in to FSMO roles, which are important, of course, but I didn't want to cloud the issue too much. (@dannymcc - Have a read of this: http://www.petri.co.il/understanding_fsmo_roles_in_ad.htm)

Comment: Excellent, that's just the kind of help I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is also a strong argument for having a local DNS server on the performance side. The DNS server caches lookups, and as users tend to hit the same FQDN often you can cut the connection time down significantly. As little as 50ms slower connections will start degrading the perceived performance of the network. OpenDNS is (in my experience) relatively fast, but there is little they can do about the transmission delay from their server to your network.

So, even if you use a service such as OpenDNS, having a local server to cache lookups gives you benefits.